GitHub Action not triggering
I have created .github/workflows/checks.yml:
name: checks

on: [push]

jobs:
  test-lint:
    name: Test and Lint
    runs-on: ubuntu-20.04
    steps:
      - name: login to Docker Hub
        uses: docker/login-action@v1
        with:
          username: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_USER }}
          password: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_TOKEN }}
      - name: checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Test
        run: docker compose run --rm app sh -c "python manage.py test"
      - name: Lint
        run: docker compose run --rm app sh -c "flake8"

In github, I see nothing when I click on action.
This image shows what I see in github.

Have u tried pushing any commits ? your workflow is set to trigger on push to your repo.

I just looked at your repo, and you have a typo: your workflow file is in .github/worflows without the k. Move it to .github/workflows/checks.yml and it'll get picked up and run by Actions.

Did you mean you wanted to click on the action to run this script? GitHub actions are actually automatically runed when you push something to GitHub(or sometimes a pull request created if you selected).
The third line of your script says on: [push], that means your script can (only) be runned when you push some commits to GitHub. GitHub actions are not used as a "quick action" or something like that. Instead, they are a kind of script that can be automatically runned.
If you need more information, please read GitHub Docs.
